# Smart way to update several properties in a list of objects with an unique window

Tags: c#, wpf, algorithm, xaml

I'm working on an edition window for an object's properties :

[image]

Right now, It works for a single object that is binded to the window. 
I'd like to use it for the update of a list of objects.

If the window is initiated with a list of objects, I use the leave event on each UIElement to detect which property has been edited, and I store the properties to update at window's closing.

Is there a more simple and elegant way to do this ?

Thank ou for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make another class,make it the Data context and in this class make a list of your elements by using `ObservableCollection<T>` .
then bind your UI elements to the properties of each element of `ObservableCollection<T>` like this :

```
PropertyInUISide="{Binding ObservableCollectionName[Propertyindex] }
```

Comment: If you put some codes and explain it more it will be more clear.